# Physical layer encoding violation framing method

Tags: networking, wired-networking

I'm confused with the method of physical layer encoding violations used in framing technique at the link layer. As much as I know, since physical layer has redundancies because of mapping single bits to more values, the method uses this to its advantage that certain bit sequences are not possible while mapping the bits. So, it uses them to mark as ending and starting of frames.

My doubt is with the example that my course instructor gave in which she told that we can map 0 to 01 and 1 to 10. So, since no mapping contains 00 or 11 they are not possible inside the data bit sequence. But if we take the bit sequence to be '01' (just for example its size is too small) then its mapping would produce '0110' as the resulting sequence which contains 11 inside it. The instructor did not provide any clear answer and I'm trying to get it on the internet but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. - This is my first time posting a question on stack exchange so any mistake is unintended and the question above is correct to the best of my knowledge

Comment: This sounds like it would fit slightly better at https://cs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Can we ask conceptual questions there? or only coding questions are allowed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on correct track. If you have locked on to the normal bits correctly, you would know that there is always a change in the middle of a bit, but between two bits there might not be a change as that is normal. If you are locked to bits correctly and know their boundaries, but still receive no change within a bit, that is the violation. Some protocols might use longer sequences than one bit to encode a violation to make it more clear, maybe by sending three or four bits of illegal sequence to lock on.

Comment: adding for more clarification on the manchester encoding violation, the 0 bit is represented as a voltage transition from 0 to 1 inside a single clock [(image)](https://images.app.goo.gl/uoSbNhWnL1jVpk5c6), that is what the change in middle of a bit means. Similar is the case for bit 1.

Answer (score 1):

> since physical layer has redundancies because of mapping single bits to more values, the method uses this to its advantage that certain bit sequences are not possible while mapping the bits. So, it uses them to mark as ending and starting of frames.

That's one possible method, yes.

But there's more: depending on details, the encoding is also done in such a way that bit errors can be corrected, by choosing "encoding targets" that have a minimum bit distance to each other. Often these targets also have some other properties, like a fixed number of 1s and 0s.

For example, consider the "2 out of 5" code: 5 bits of which exactly 2 are 1. There are ten ways to do that:

```
A 11000
B 10100
C 10010
D 10001
E 01100
F 01010
G 01001
H 00110
I 00101
J 00011
```

All of these differ in at least two bit changes. So you could use the eight codes A-H to encode `000` to `111`, and then you have I and J for framing.

And there's lots of variations on this idea.

---

If the question is about "how to find the boundaries of code": You can have a special synchronisation and training phase, which is used in particular for faster point-to-point connections. When you loose synchronisation (you get too many errors), you retrain.

You can also have self-synchronization by using special properties of the code. For example, 100BASE-X Ethernet uses [4B5B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4B5B) Codes, with the property that

> Three consecutive zero bits only appear in normal data when a code ending with two 0 bits (2, E) is followed by a code beginning with a 0 bit (1, 4, 5, 6, 7), so will always appear separated by multiples of the 5-bit encoded symbol length (and never separated by a single symbol). Violations of this property are used for special synchronization codes.

And the start sequence is `JK` or `11000 10001`, which will have three consecutive 0 bits twice, but **not** separated by a multiple of the 5-bit symbol length. So this particular sequence cannot appear in a normal data stream.

Again, there are many variations on that idea.

Comment: my doubt was about the chance flags occur inside the message. Suppose I used the codes A and B to encode my message, then resulting sequence is AB -> 1100010100 which contains I (flag), so I detected the flag inside message. So how to look for that ?